# Make caption look right in greek

Tags: captions

i'm having trouble trying to make a caption look right. I want to write in Greek the "figure" name, that is, "Σχήμα". The problem is after I put

```
\addto{\captionsenglish}{
      \renewcommand{\figurename}
        {\tg{Σχήμα}}
}
```

in the preamble,
the output is

> ΣΧΗ'ΜΑ 1.1(some figure name}

instead of

> Σχήμα 1.1(some figure name)

meaning that the problem is the output is with capital.
any idea?

MINIMAL EXAMPLE UPDATE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Book}
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis} 
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newcommand{\tg}{\textgreek}
\newcommand{\tl}{\textlatin}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{
      \renewcommand{\figurename}
        {\tg{Σχήμα}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\hspace{-4.5em}\includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{Pictures/data.png}
\rule{35em}{0.5pt}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

does the job...but not in my main project

UPDATE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%  Thesis.CLS   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
\addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows the use of international characters (e.g. Umlauts)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\thesistitle}[1]{\def\ttitle{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT VARIABLES
%   Fill in the lines below to update the thesis template
%   If you wish to cite each of the variables defined below, look at the
%   section above for the citation command e.g. \examiner{} below is
%   defined as \examname above so you cite it as \examname
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Thesis Title} % Your thesis title - this is used in the title and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------  
\supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} % You supervisor's name - this is used in the title page
%-------------------------------------------------   
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \examname if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name - this is currently used in the title page and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------   
\authors{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name - this is used in the title page and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------   
\addresses{} % Your address - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \addressnames if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\subject{} % Your subject area - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \subjectname if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \keywordnames if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\university{\texorpdfstring{\href{http://www.university.com} % Your university's URL
                {University Name}} % Your university's name - this is currently used in the title page
                {University Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------   
\UNIVERSITY{\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your university's URL
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your university's name in capitals - this is currently used in the abstract page
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\department{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
                {Department or School Name}} % Your department's name - used in the title page and abstract
                {Department or School Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\DEPARTMENT{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your department's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \DEPTNAME if you want it
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\group{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
                {Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name - this is currently used in the title page 
                {Research Group Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\GROUP{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your research group's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \GROUPNAME if you want it
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\faculty{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your faculty's URL
                {Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name - this is currently used in the abstract page
                {Faculty Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\FACULTY{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your faculty's URL
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your faculty's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \FACNAME if you want it
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

% The default title page, this is not used in this www.latextemplates.com version            
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
      {\large degree of \degreename \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large in the \par}
      {\large \facname \par}
      {\large \deptname \par} 
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par} % University name in capitals
    \bigskip
    {\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \facname \par} % Faculty name
    {\normalsize \deptname \par} % Department name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \degreename\par} % Degree name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bf \@title \par} % Thesis title
    \medskip
    {\normalsize by \authornames \par} % Author name
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\addtotoc{Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
```

Comment: You should be doing `\usepackage[greek]{babel}` rather than trying to coerce English into Greek. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: i ve added the \usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

Comment: If your document's main language is Greek, say `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}`. But a minimal example is needed anyway: what's `\tg`, for instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your document is in Greek, you don't need to specify `\tg` every time; just set Greek as the main language and omit the `english` option if you don't need to write in English.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % or utf8x if you really need it
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]
  {/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minitoc/greece-f.png}

\caption{Νήματα (εσωτερική δομή).}\label{fig:Threads}
\end{figure}

Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you occasionally (or even frequently) need to insert English words, use `babel`'s facilities:

```
\newcommand{\engterm}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
```

and then input a paragraph like

```
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων \engterm{something}
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
```

If you need a long passage in English (a complete paragraph), insert it with the `otherlanguage*` environment:

```
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων \engterm{something}
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
Here is a paragraph in English, that can go on for some lines.
\end{otherlanguage*}

Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
Δήλωση Προστασίας Πνευματικών Δικαιωμάτων
```

(Sorry, but my Greek is inexistent, I just used a phrase from another question of yours.) Of course you can define your own environment

```
\newenvironment{engpar}
  {\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}}
  {\end{otherlanguage*}}
```

Comment: i use both greek and english and english as my main language

Comment: @kostas Can you be more precise about this? Do you have complete chapters in English?

Comment: not complete...a mixture.Its my thesis.My main language is greek but it has a lot of terminology in english...

Comment: any admin here i have one more question...

Comment: @kostas If I change `\documentclass{article}` into `\documentclass{Thesis}` in the example document, I get the same result with “Σχήμα” as the figure tag. Of course, if you insist in setting English as default language, you'll be the cause of your troubles.